# how to login automatically after signup in django class base view

Tags: python, django

i want to login automatically user when successful signup.

but my code return anonymous user now

so, i use CreateView in django CBV

*views.py*

```py
class SignUpView(CreateView):
  template_name = 'users/signup.html'
  success_url = reverse_lazy('users:email_confirm_notice')
  form_class = CustomUserCreationForm

  def form_valid(self, form):
    user = form.save()
    login(self.request, user)
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

and i try it

```py
def form_valid(self, form):
  form.save()
  new_user = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data.get('username'), password.cleaned_data.get('password1'))
  login(self.request, new_user)
  return super().form_valid(form)
```

success_url is TemplateView that is just display templates and customusercreationform change error message.

it is expected that there will be no changes from the first function.

What's my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i solved it...

but i didn't understand why it worked this way.

I just change the code like below.

*SignupView/form_vaild()*

```py
def form_valid(self, form):
    valid = super().form_valid(form)
    login(self.request, self.object)
    return valid
```

it's acting..